# How can I do paging in Sybase without making temp table? (oracle rownum issue)

Tags: paging, sybase, rowcount

In Oracle, usually query like this for paging.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, rownum rid  FROM TABLEA WHERE rownum <= #pageend#)
WHERE rid > #pagestart#
```

However, there is no "rownum" function in Sybase DBMS.

How can I do that query exactlly same in Sybase?

I found some ways.

1. use "rowcount"

   set rowcount 10

   select * from TABLEA
2. use identity (make temp table)

   SELECT *, ROWNUM=IDENTITY(8) INTO #TEMP FROM TABLEA

   SELECT * FROM #TEMP WHERE ROWNUM < #pageend# AND ROWNUM >= #pagestart#

   DROP TABLE #TEMP

these are not what I want.

rowcount is set at the session level and i don't want make temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a unique id column on your table you could use SELECT TOP n

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM tableA
WHERE id BETWEEN @start AND @end
```

Comment: Is this a good idea? How do I know that the id column starts at 1? And has no holes in it? I think this is not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you all the **ids** so you  can use them in a select like "`select * where id_column in (ids from query below)`"

```
select top 10 id_column from trade
where @whereClause
and id_column > 0  //keep replacing this with the max id from the result set
order by id_column
```