# limit and offset not working in sybase 15.7

Tags: sybase

I want to implement pagination. I tried following query 
Below query will display clients from 11 to 20
*SELECT * FROM Client ORDER BY ClientName DESC LIMIT 11,10;*

But it is giving following Error::
Error: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 102

My Sybase version is

> Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 21153 SMP SP100 
>   Please let me know any alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase 15.7 does not support LIMIT and OFFSET. Some people have implemented a workaround to generate an artificial row count sequence to allow for easier pagination.

[Sybase offset for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759166/sybase-offset-for-pagination)

[How can I do paging in Sybase without making temp table? (oracle rownum issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225889/how-can-i-do-paging-in-sybase-without-making-temp-table-oracle-rownum-issue)

[Sybase Reference Manual: Commands: Select](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X35229.htm)
[Sybase Transact SQL Users Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/title.htm)